# Multiple Target App with single Info.plist file fails to export for translation

Tags: ios, xcode, translation, xliff

Strange issue:

I have a project with tens of targets and a single Info.plist file because it uses variables for it's data. This makes it easier to maintain if I need new ones added.

I need to translate this app by using XLIFF files. The problem is that the export dialog gives a "Duplicate info.plist export for localization" error and stops. This happens because all targets use the same Info.plist

If I remove the entry from all targets and leave it to just one, it works fine but it's a lot of work to do each time.

Now, a good solution would be to add the plist file to the project's entry which it seems would make it work for all targets, but it doesn't. Xcode complaints on build that the Info.plist file has not been found.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This has been fixed in Xcode 9!